# Turn off Drupal caching without Access to admin panel

Tags: drush, caching

I'm using Drupal 7 on WAMPP , Windows 7

Background: Drupal on my local box is copy of working project, but this local version I can not login like admin , because it doesn't store session. It doesn't give out any PHP Error.

So I guess I have to turn off cache to find out , is there any PHP Error appearing.

Read that there is such thing as `drush` , but is it possible to use from Windows ?

But the main question , is how to stop caching on Windows 7 without Admin access !?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can run Drush under Microsoft Windows if you use the [Drush Windows Installer](http://www.drush.org/drush_windows_installer). Drush will allow you to turn of caching with the command:

```
drush en cache_disable --yes
```

It is not *easy* to set up the Drush Windows Installer.  As an alternative, you may consider explicitly set variables in your `settings.php` to turn of various caches.  Note that when set, these values will be locked to whatever is set in the file, and cannot be changed through the admin interface (so remove them when you're done debugging).

To disable page, JS, and CSS caching, set cache, preprocess_js, and preprocess_css all to '0' in the `$conf` array:

```
$conf = array(
  'cache' => '0',
  'preprocess_css' => '0',
  'preprocess_js' => '0',
);
```

If you set other values by means of the `$conf` array, add these fields, do that, rather than replacing the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this link](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/display_cache-disable_on_the_fly-2499055-13.patch) you can see disable cache by puting below line in `settings.php` files

```
  $conf['display_cache_disable'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: "Also" to what, exactly? Is this a full answer? If so, please make that clear. If not, add an excerpt and link to part you are referring, so your answer would continue to be an answer even if the other one gets deleted.